# Round decimals for multiple averages and condensing avg?

Tags: sql, sqlite, rounding, average

I was wondering if there was any way to condense this select statement?

as well as if it is possible to round each result to a certain amount of decimals?

It is set up correctly and giving me the right result but I was just wondering if there was any way to tighten it up? I am using SQLite

```
SELECT  AVG(eFG),
        AVG(OPP_eFG),
        AVG(TOV_PCT),
        AVG(OPP_TOV_PCT),
        AVG(ORB_PCT),
        AVG(DRB_PCT),
        AVG(FTA_RATE),
        AVG(OPP_FTA_RATE)
```

Comment: Feel free to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about the site rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [ROUND() function](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-round.php)

> SQLite round() function rounds a floating-point value t up to a number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If the 2nd argument (rounded digits) is omitted, it is assumed to be 0.

```
SELECT  ROUND(AVG(eFG),2),
        ROUND(AVG(OPP_eFG),2),
        ROUND(AVG(TOV_PCT),2),
        ROUND(AVG(OPP_TOV_PCT),2),
        ROUND(AVG(ORB_PCT),2),
        ROUND(AVG(DRB_PCT),2),
        ROUND(AVG(FTA_RATE),2),
        ROUND(AVG(OPP_FTA_RATE),2)
```